# Query or Filter the Highest Value with Conditions

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, formulas

so I have this thing here below. I have been breaking my head for the past 2 days trying to figure it out.

[image: Tada]

On a separate page, I want to be able to know THE DATE of someone's best performance (Fronts, Spiffs, Apps separately) so I've tried the following

```
=offset(index('Junkyard 2'!K2:K1999,(MATCH(MAX('Junkyard 2'!K2:K1999),'Junkyard 2'!K2:K1999,0))),0,-9)
```

That gets me the date with the highest number but it is not necessarily from that person

So I've tried

```
=FILTER('Junkyard 2'!B3:B2000,'Junkyard 2'!C3:C2000=B4,LARGE('Junkyard 2'!K3:K2000,1))
```

And it gives me this

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1998, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

So now I've tried query but I'm shit at query to be honest, don't understand much.

```
=QUERY('Junkyard 2'!B3:O2000,"select B, Max(K) group by B"  )
```

This gives me the maximum of each day..again, not neccesarily done by the guy.

In a jist, I want to be able get the Day with Highest Number of Fronts/spiffs/apps that a guy I choose have done. It's so annoying.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that on a separate sheet, in cell A2 create a Data Validation dropdown of the names on Junkyard 2 column B. Then on the new sheet in B2 enter:

```
=QUERY('Junkyard 2'!A2:O2005, "Select A, K where B = '" & A2 &"' ORDER BY K  DESC LIMIT 1")
```

It will return the date and the max value from column K for the person selected in the Data Validation dropdown.

Comment: Yeah I have another page with a validation dropdown. I noticed that this does not give me the maximum. in some cases it works, in some it does not. would doing 
`=QUERY('Junkyard 2'!A2:O2005, "Select A, K where B = '" & A2 &"' ORDER BY MAX(K)  DESC LIMIT 1")` work? 

Yeah i noticed that any numbers above 9 would not be counted in this formula. Is that normal?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem you are having with the formula. I only recreated a small part of your data, but I always get the max. If you want to share your spreadsheet I will take a look.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MtxzvTz_aP-4WICMfYV3U-4EPXqwDca-NUlW98cjRq0/edit?usp=sharing) please check the individual fronters tab

Comment: I can only view the spreadsheet. I really need to be able to make a copy.

Comment: sorry, i changed it now

Comment: I see the problem. It is how the Order By is sorting numbers. 10 and 12 are sorting after 1. To see an example use Guillermo Padilla and change Limit 1 to Limit 60. You will see the problem. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: OK. I think I have it. I am sharing the spreadsheet I created.
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tNuO_1mEPEVpg2N6RJkv5yrI_q6OfGcBjgKdLwKC_V4/edit?usp=sharing.
 Note that I removed the Labels in the formulas I used. The other thing I had to do is go to the 3 
columns K, L, and M  on 'Junkyard 2' and sort them Z-A. This seems to fix the sort problem with 10, 12 
comong after 2. Let me know. If not I guess we should move this to chat as recommended.

Comment: Well the only issue is that Junkyard data are automatically pulled from various other sheets and tabs so sorting it would not be a viable solution. I appreciate all that you've done. If you don't mind helping me then we can move onto the chat. Thanks If not i'll just mark it as done

Comment: I added a sheet to the link above with a note in cell A1. Please read  the note of what I did. I think this will work for you.

Comment: I added another query option. Notes on how it works are in the note in A2,