# I want to display the highest age of each gender and all the marks of that person

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| Gender | Name | English | Hindi | Maths | Science | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Rajesh | 68 | 56 | 67 | 95 | 14 |
| Male | Suresh | 83 | 99 | 85 | 88 | 15 |
| Male | Amit | 56 | 60 | 60 | 92 | 14 |
| Male | Punit | 90 | 68 | 86 | 99 | 12 |
| Male | Rahul | 75 | 57 | 68 | 62 | 16 |
| Male | Alok | 60 | 76 | 67 | 95 | 16 |
| Female | Renuka | 61 | 64 | 95 | 70 | 12 |
| Female | Rekha | 92 | 62 | 64 | 79 | 13 |
| Female | Sonam | 85 | 57 | 62 | 95 | 16 |
| Female | Shalini | 60 | 57 | 98 | 72 | 14 |

Output

| Gender | Name | English | Hindi | Maths | Science | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Alok | 60 | 76 | 67 | 95 | 16 |
| Female | Sonam | 85 | 57 | 62 | 95 | 16 |

Answer (score 0):

### Try:

**For Male:**

```
=QUERY(A2:G11,"Select * where A='Male' order by G desc limit 1")
```

**For Female:**

```
=QUERY(A2:G11,"Select * where A='Female' order by G desc limit 1")
```

**Result:**
[image]

**Explanation:**
The formula uses `query()` which filters the range where column A=Male or Female, then sorts it by descending based on Column G. Then it only displays the first value.

**Reference:** [Query or Filter the Highest Value with Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947445/query-or-filter-the-highest-value-with-conditions)